# Bootstrap Rails 5 not styling my app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-5

I just installed **bootstrap** into my rails project and followed all their instructions on their **GitHub** page but now only certain elements are getting bootstrap styled. I can style the links with `btn btn-primary` but `btn btn-default` doesn't work.

Also, when I try:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home3</a></li>
</ul>
```

It doesn't style this list fully.

[image]

Here is my ***gemfile***:

```
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha6'
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-tether', '>= 1.3.3'
end
```

And i did do this in my ***Application.css.scss***:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this gem into your ***gemfile***:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
```

***app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss***

```
// "bootstrap-sprockets" must be imported before "bootstrap" and "bootstrap/variables"
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

references: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass